# Книги по юзабилити

Tags: книги

Привет! 
Нужно по работе изучить материалы по юзабилити. Прочитала книгу GUI Bloopers. Она, конечно, ничего, но некоторые главы устарели. Посоветуйте книги по юзабилити и проектированию пользовательского интерфейса. Интересуют как Web, так и desktop приложения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне еще такие книги посоветовали:

- Алан Купер "Психбольница в руках пациентов"
- Алан Купер "Об интерфейсе" (About Faces)
- Дэвид Платт "Софт - отстой"